# Lambda Calculus, applicative vs normal order

Tags: computer-science, lambda-calculus

I just started learning lambda calculus, and i have this question to do with normal order and in applicative order:

```
(λfx.f (f x))(λfx.f (f x)) f x
```

In normal order, I got the answer of `(f (f (f (f x))))`.

I tried applicative order like this:

```
-> (λfx.f (f x))(λfx.f (f x)) a b
-> (λfx.f (f x))(λx.a (a x)) b
-> (λfx.f (f x))(a (a b))
-> (λx.(a (a b)) ((a (a b)) x))
```

But I think this is wrong, so I asked the professor, and he gave me the "starting" portion of the solution, but I don't really understand it:

```
   (λfx.f (f x))(λfx.f (f x)) f x
-> (λyx.y (y x))((λyx.y (y x)) f) x
-> (λyz.y (y z)) f ((λyz.y (y z)) f x) ;why is there an extra f?
```

My question is: why does the solution start off like this? Why does changing the variables add another $f$ in the middle?

Comment: Should the term you wrote be intended as $\big( (\lambda fx.f (f x))(\lambda fx.f (f x)) \big) f x$? If it is so, both your attempt of following the applicative order and your professor's hint are wrong.

Comment: No, i don't think so? The problem I posted above is exactly how it's written by the professor. Thank you for pointing that out though, I'll keep that in mind and ask the professor!  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under [normal order evaluation](https://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/normal+order+reduction), an expression is evaluated by reducing the leftmost outermost $\beta$-redex first. 
So, in your example you get:

\begin{align}
(\lambda fx.f (f x))(\lambda fx.f (f x)) f x &= \big(\lambda fx.f (f x)\big)(\lambda gy.g (g y)) f x 
\\
&\to \big(\lambda x. (\lambda gy.g (g y)) ((\lambda gy.g (g y)) x) \big) f x 
\\
&\to \big(\lambda gy.g (g y) \big) ((\lambda gy.g (g y)) f)  x 
\\
&= \big(\lambda gy.g (g y) \big) ((\lambda gz.g (g z)) f)  x 
\\
&\to \big(\lambda y. ((\lambda gz.g (g z)) f) ( ((\lambda gz.g (g z)) f) y) \big) x 
\\
&\to \big(\lambda gz.g (g z)\big) f  ( ((\lambda gz.g (g z)) f) x) 
\\
&\to \big(\lambda z.f (f z)\big)  ( ((\lambda gz.g (g z)) f) x) 
\\
&\to f (f  ( ( \big(\lambda gz.g (g z) \big) f) x) )
\\
&\to f (f  ( \big(\lambda z.f (f z) \big) x) )
\\
&\to f (f  ( f (f x) ) )
\end{align}

According to [applicative order evaluation](https://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/applicative+order+reduction), function's arguments are evaluated before the function is applied. In the $\lambda$-calculus, it means that you reduce the leftmost $\beta$-redex $(\lambda x. M)N$ provided that $N$ is a *value*, i.e. a variable or an abstraction.

\begin{align}
(\lambda fx.f (f x))(\lambda fx.f (f x)) f x &= \big(\lambda fx.f (f x)\big)(\lambda gy.g (g y)) f x 
\\
&\to \big(\lambda x. (\lambda gy.g (g y)) ((\lambda gy.g (g y)) x) \big) f x 
\\
&\to (\lambda gy.g (g y) ) (\big(\lambda gy.g (g y)\big) f)  x 
\\
&\to \big(\lambda gy.g (g y) \big) (\lambda y.f (f y))  x 
\\
&= \big(\lambda gy.g (g y) \big) (\lambda z.f (f z))  x 
\\
&\to \big(\lambda y. (\lambda z.f (f z)) ( (\lambda z.f (f z)) y) \big)  x 
\\
&\to  (\lambda z.f (f z) ) ( f (f x)) 
\end{align}

You can see the difference between the two evaluation orders after two $\beta$-steps, when you get the term $(\lambda gy.g (g y) ) ((\lambda gy.g (g y)) f)  x $: this term has the form $(\lambda g. M_g) ((\lambda g.M_g) f)  x $ with $M_g = \lambda y.g (g y)$, so the leftmost $\beta$-redex is $(\lambda g. M_g) ((\lambda g.M_g) f)$ where the argument $(\lambda g.M_g) f$ is not a value. So, the leftmost $\beta$-redex can be reduced under normal order evaluation, but not according to applicative order evaluation, for which you have first to reduce the argument to a value.

Note that the last term I wrote in the applicative order evaluation is stuck because the argument $f(fx)$ of the $\beta$-redex is not a value and then we cannot perform any further $\beta$-steps.

The fact that in this case normal order and applicative order evaluations yield different results is not surprising.
Indeed, they yield the same result provided that the starting term is *closed*, and your starting term is not closed (the last occurrences of $f$ and $x$ are free).

Some definitions of applicative order are more lax and allows you to reduce the term $(\lambda z.f (f z) ) ( f (f x)) $ because the argument $f(fx)$ of the $\beta$-redex is fully evaluated, although it is not a value. So you will get 
\begin{align}
 (\lambda z.f (f z) ) ( f (f x)) \to f(f(f(fx)))
\end{align}
also under this extended sense of applicative order.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation!  ^^