# Lambda calculus normal order - what is "outermost"?

Tags: lambda-calculus

I have a question regarding lambda calculus normal order reduction.  Essentially every explanation I've found is similar to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3567807/646063), which describes the order as ([reduce] the leftmost **outermost** $\beta$-redex first" (bold is mine), and then proceeds to enact what I would just think of as the "leftmost" (when reading the string from left to right) applications.

"Leftmost outermost" seems to apply two coequal criteria, but I can't even seem to find the second term being enacted.  What does the word **outermost** mean in this context, and how would the ordering be different if it weren't there?

Comment: (in normal order) Leftmost outermost = out of the outermost (highest in the syntax tree), take the leftmost one.  
(in applicative order): Leftmost innermost = out of the innermost (lowest in the syntax tree), take the leftmost one. These do not, in the general case, coincide.

Comment: @lemontree Wouldn't that, in all circumstances, also be the leftmost in the string?  Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: No. E.g. in $(\lambda x. ((\lambda y. y) x))z$, the (only and leftmost) outermost redex is $(\lambda x. ((\lambda y. y) x))z$ whereas the (only and leftmost) innermost redex is $(\lambda y. y) x$. The leftmost redex globally is not an innermost redex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the definition of *leftmost*, the adjective *outermost* may be or not be  superfluous.

The most common meaning of *leftmost* is the one pointed out by Lemontree in his comment, and it refers to the syntactic tree associated with each $\lambda$-term. First, you define the notion of outermost and innermost redexes.
In a $\lambda$-term $M$, a redex is

- *outermost* if it is not a subterm of any other  redex in $M$;
- *innermost* if it does not contain any other redexes as subterms.

A term may contain several outermost redexes and several innermost redexes. For instance, in the $\lambda$-term $x ((\lambda y.y)y) ((\lambda z.z)z)$, the two redexes are outermost (and innermost too!). Two fix an order so as to define an evaluation strategy, we choose the leftmost or the rightmost redex *among* the outermost or innermost ones, where *leftmost* (resp. *rightmost*) means the one that occurs leftmost (resp. rightmost) in the syntax tree of the $\lambda$-term. In this way, there is at most one leftmost-outermost redex in a $\lambda$-term, and similarly for leftmost-innermost, rightmost-innermost, etc.

Clearly, this definition of leftmost (and of rightmost) makes sense only together with the notion of outermost or innermost.

A second possible meaning of *leftmost* is less common but it is used for instance in [Krivine's textbook](https://www.irif.fr/%7Ekrivine/articles/Lambda.pdf). Since a redex has necessarily the form $(\lambda x.M)N$, in every $\lambda$-term, each subsequence of the form "$(\lambda$" corresponds to a unique redex in that term. We can then define the *leftmost* redex in a $\lambda$-term $M$ as the redex whose "$(\lambda$" part occurs leftmost in $M$, seen as a string of characters.

In this second definition of leftmost, the adjective outermost is clearly superfluous: the leftmost redex (in this second meaning) is necessarily outermost (in the sense defined above). Actually, this second meaning of *leftmost* coincides with the definition of *leftmost-outermost* above: both definitions identify the *same* redex in a $\lambda$-term (if any), although they follow a different procedure to identify it. Indeed, the only difference is in the meaning of the word "leftmost" in the definitions of "leftmost-outermost redex" and of "leftmost redex".

In the literature, the definition of the normal order reduction via the notion leftmost-outermost redex is common (and often preferred to the one via the second meaning of leftmost) because it is flexible: indeed, using the same approach one can define other evaluation strategies based on the leftmost-innermost redex, the rightmost-innermost redex, etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136557/discussion-between-ben-i-and-taroccoesbrocco).